# How to enable VNC permanently on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: vnc

My goal is to access my raspberry pi 4 remotely after turning it on. I learnt about VNC and tried it using raspi-config in a terminal window. It worked perfectly. The only problem I’m facing is, I have to do this again every time I reboot the system. Is there a way to permanently enable VNC so that I don’t have to enable it every time I switch it on?

The only post question to mine that I found in the archive is [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95514/vnc-disabled-after-each-reboot). It didn’t help.

Comment: You should only have to enable it once. Has your micro sd card failed and gone read only? Which OS are you using?

Comment: You have not included any details in your question. The Pi4 has no display without a monitor.

Comment: @CoderMike thank you, it was indeed ON. I got mislead by the way in which the configuration menu was displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably started the VNC service by hand, either by starting the vnc server directly or via `sudo systemctl start vncserver-x11-serviced.service`.

To make it permanent, starting the vnc server via the configuration menu `raspi-config` should have done it, but via

```
sudo systemctl enable vncserver-x11-serviced.service
```

you can do it manually from the CLI.

Comment: The OP has already stated that raspi-config was used.